# Liferay: Can't see the deployed portlet

Tags: jsf, portlet, liferay

I develop a sample JSF portlet for the Liferay portal. 
After I had deployed it (no errors in the console and the .war file from the *liferay/deploy* directory is removed to the *liferay/tomcat/webapps* and is exploded). I tried to add this portlet to a new page via Liferay's admin console. The problem is - I can't find my portlet. 
I've tried to deploy an example portlet from Liferay's site and everything was ok. All the .xml files are completely the same as in the example.

Could somebody help me?

UPDATE: I've found listenerStart error in tomcat output. What can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for my problem lays in the portlet.xml file.
There are several `<init-param/>` tags. One of them should look like the following for the JSF portlet (myfaces):

```
    <init-param>
        <name>default-view</name>
        <value>/index.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you added the correct permissions to the portlet? You could either try to access it in the menu when using an adminstator account. 
Does the portlet appear in the administration console as deployed? 
Also: what do the logs tell you? Is it deployed properly or did any error occur?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, see update about the error. About the priviledges: I use administrator account and there are role-mappers for all of the user categories, i.e. <role-mapper>
  <role-name>administrator</role-name>
  <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
 </role-mapper>

Comment: about the listenerStart: hard to tell without any further information. Could you post the stacktrace? Does the portlet show up if you look in the administration console where all the other portlets are registered? You should also check the permissions there if it is listed.

Comment: I have deleted the web.xml file (Liferay can substitute it), the new problem raise up. com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException^ error registering portlets for MyPortlet... I have read that this problem might occur when there is a portlet.jar in the portal's classpath. But there is no...

Comment: This can indeed occur in lots of situations. Without any further info like a stacktrace it's hard to tell. Personally I would suggest to create a blank portlet from scratch (using the SDK functionality) and then add bit by bit. In Liferays' SVN there are some example portlets as well that might be closer to what you need than the default one.

Comment: You should be able to copy it (e.g. in windows: right click -> select or something like that). Did you have an success with the freshly created portlet or any of the examples?